# Как, сортируя один массив в случайном порядке, отсортировать еще один в точно таком же порядке?

Tags: c#

```
private static System.Random rng = new System.Random();
public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list, IList<T> list2)  
    {  
        int n = list.Count;  
        while (n > 1) {  
            n--;  
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
            T value = list[k];  
            list[k] = list[n];  
            list[n] = value;  
        }  
    }
```

Сортирует значения какого-нибудь `List` в случайном порядке. А как сделать так, чтобы `List2` отсортировался в точно таком же порядке?

Comment: повтори те же три строки с заменой для list2

Comment: Пытался, не получилось. А потом я внимательно строка за строкой просмотрел, как именно я пытался, и нашел ошибку. Спасибо, как комментарии отмечать в качестве ответа?

Comment: Никак :-) отмечай ответ, который уже есть, либо можешь написать свой собственный ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Генератор случайных числе* в .NET позволяет повторно генерировать ту же цепочку чисел, если инициализировать его одним и тем же исходным числом — *зерном* (*seed*).

```
var random1 = new Random(100);
Suffle(list, random1);

var random2 = new Random(100);
Suffle(list2, random);

public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list, Random rng)  
{  
    int n = list.Count;
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, тоже заработает, но использовал вариант из комментария

Comment: Интересно, когда мы создаем `new Random()` без указания параметра, можно ли потом узнать значение, которое было использовано?

Comment: @Андрей, Не можем: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, да уже смотрю исходники - Seed никуда не сохраняется